# Как правильно передать несколько параметров в контроллер на ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Пишу RTB (аукцион в режиме реального времени) приложение, (если кому интересно, то вот [ссылка на спецификацию](https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/OpenRTB-API-Specification-Version-2-5-FINAL.pdf)).
**Вопрос, как правильно будет передать в контроллер n-кол-во параметров (например, 25 или 50)** на ASP.NET Core 3.1 (.Net Framework 5).

Пока придумал только 2 варианта:

1. Передавать все параметры, как переменные (т.е. указать в контроллере все необходимые параметры)
2. Создать модель, заполнить ее, а потом в контроллер передать уже подготовленную модель

Comment: Если параметры одного типа и их количество заранее неизвестно - можно передавать как json-коллекцию. Если разного и количество параметров известно - создать модель и заполнить ее. В любом случае, принимать эти параметры нужно через http-запросы, предполагающие тело запроса (например. POST).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, а как тогда можно заполнить модель? Получается надо будет создовать дополнительный Action в контроллере?

Comment: Объявите класс Request с 25 или 50 свойствами, в экшен объявите что входной параметр имеет имя request тип Request. Ох, с таким уровнем знаний лезть в тему HFT - наломаете дров....

Comment: @Nikita все зависит от того, кто должен вызывать метод контроллера. Вы должны отправить http запрос и в него вложить тело запроса (request body). В интернете найдете много информации о том, как это можно сделать с помощью разных языков программирования или технологий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы объявлять 25 или 50 параметров в экшене (больше трёх стараются не делать для читаемости) объявите класс Request в котором объявите все эти свойства:

```
public class Request
{
   property string FirstName { get; set; }
   property string LastName { get; set; }
   property string MiddleName { get; set; }
   // ....
}
```

И укажите в качестве параметра вашего экшена:

```
public IActionResult MyAction(Request request)
{
   // ...
}
```

Если же параметры единообразны - используйте массивы:

```
public class Request
{
   property string FirstName { get; set; }
   property string LastName { get; set; }
   property string MiddleName { get; set; }

   property int[] Ids { get; set; }
   // ....
}
```

И не знаю, ваше ли дело кто и как будет это в контроллер передавать... То ли это внешний javascript будет, толи это вы сами будете вызывать из какого-то кода, но каков вопрос — таков ответ.