# Как правильно передать несколько параметров в контроллер?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться с параметрами контроллера.
Есть контроллер

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Auction([FromQuery] int[] ids, [FromQuery] decimal[] price, [FromQuery] string platfrom, AuctionModel auctionModel)
        {
            // Код
        }
```

можно как нибудь упростить этот код? Мне кажется что тут слшком много [FromQuery], пробовал так, но на выходе была ошибка

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Auction([FromQuery] int[] ids, decimal[] price, string platfrom, AuctionModel auctionModel)
        {
            // Код
        }
```

Comment: Когда вы в простой программе описываете некий объект, вы что делаете? Правильно, класс, который в себе содержит все необходимые значения. Что мешает это сделать и здесь?

Comment: Создайте отдельный класс: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1276747/213987

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[FromQuery]` не может быть "слишком много". Их должно быть ровно столько, сколько параметров нужно передать через адресную строку.

С другой стороны, если вы желаете спрятать эти параметры из адресной строки, вы можете изменить атрибут метода на `[HttpPost]` и передавать параметры в теле запроса в формате form-data или json.

В последнем случае сигнатура метода будет попроще:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Auction([FromBody] AuctionData data))
{
    // Код
}

public class AuctionData {
    public int[] Ids {get;set;}
    public decimal[] Price {get;set;}
    public string Platform {get;set;}
    public AuctionModel AuctionModel {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Ещё неплохо бы упомянуть, что FromBody может быть только один в методе: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api